# crystal report freezes the whole application

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a WINFORM project in which I have used crystal report, it works fine.
Now , I am trying to add some features on existing project. So simply copy the whole folder into a new folder. At first it was window was showing message that "Filename is too long..." so renamed the folder to a short name. And it works fine with crystal report.

My issue is whenever I start coding to add new feature and run debug to test, at the point where it needs to generate crystal report whole application freezes and crystal report is not generated and no error message, I have to stop debugging from Visual studio to start over.
I have tried same with earlier projects and it worked fine , but this time don't know what I am missing.

I am using WIN8
I have googled it but not found any relevant results.

Thanks